# Is it possible to run Bitcoin on Google App Engine? / alternatives?

Tags: google-app-engine, hosting, bitcoin

This question is cross-posted on [bitcoin.stackexchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4028/is-it-possible-to-run-bitcoin-on-google-app-engine-alternatives), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146996/is-it-possible-to-run-bitcoin-on-google-app-engine-alternatives) and [bitcointalks](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=88949.0).

---

I'm planning to build an application on Google App Engine that will heavily make use of Bitcoin trading. I've been Googling along a little but I couldn't find whether it is possible to run Bitcoin itself on App Engine (with Java). I have some experience with App Engine, but limited to a pure web-app centered usage.
I've read about a few people that have made applications using Bitcoin with App Engine as well that are hosting Bitcoin separately on an Amazon EC2 instance.

So, does anyone here either has experience with running Bitcoin in App Engine for Java or would anyone have an idea how this could possibly be done? 
I know there are a lot of Bitcoin applications out there, I'd like to know how these manage their Bitcoin traffic.

I'm trying to avoid needing a separate Amazon service running all the time next to App Engine.

In fact, receiving Bitcoin can easily be done by using passive APIs like [blockexplorer](http://blockexplorer.com/) or [blockchain](https://blockchain.info/), so I'm considering to find a reliable API to handle my outgoing payments. But this approach causes extreme dependency on this API service, which I actually want to avoid as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you summed up the possiblities already.

- depend on an external service providing notifications for
  transactions and sending them i would advise against this.
- have a second server running permanently and connect to it using json-rpc

running any type of p2p node on app engine will fail, because of the threading limitations on GAE.

a third possibility would be to use a stratum/electrum supernode, that way you are dependant on a 3rd party service, but at least it is well documented and you can set up one yourself easily. AFAIK, stratum is based on http.

source: i programmed a GAE app dealing with bitcoins about 6 monts ago. (using the second server approach)